# How to Access Parquet Octet/Stream Data in GCP Using Jupyter Notbook

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, parquet

Is it possible to access/read data stored in Google Cloud Bucket? I am not the owner/creator of the Google Cloud Bucket. My hope is to access the data stored in the bucket from my Jupyter Notebook. I have seen that you can create a virtual machine tied to the Google Cloud account and access via Jupyter Notebook that way. I am assuming there are keys I'll need to request from the owner of the Google Cloud bucket? Additionally, the files do not have a file type (e.g. csv/json). When downloaded locally, there is no file type assigned.

Thank you in advance! I am happy to provide additional details as needed.

Note: I have successfully read the data downloaded locally using the following script. However, the parquet data is shifted. I'm thinking I may need to define the schema/dataframe to have aligned columns? Either way, the goal is to read directly from GCP to not have to store all of the data locally.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.parquet("filepath")
df.show(5)
```